# move an Ektron website to a new server without eSync

Tags: web-deployment, ektron

I am using a highly patched version 8.0.1 SP1.

I have a lot of website sites to move from one hosting server and database to another. I have tried to use eSync but our version has a lot patches and I have spent days trying to work out a basic eSync. Not wanting the headache, I am going to attempt a manual move. I started a test run of the steps at http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v802/webhelp/Installation/Installing%20Ektron%20CMS400.Net/Moving_a_Site_to_Another.htm but that won't set up all of the hooks into the Ektron Windows service and the notification service, etc. Am I assuming right?

Will this work?

1. Install new minsite on new server and create new database. (this should create all the bits and parts that the Ektron services need)
2. Copy website from old server and paste on top of new
3. Backup old database and restore to new
4. Copy asset folder from old site and paste into new

Will this give me all of the parts I need or am I missing something? Once we start this process, it is a one-way street and we have over 100 sites to move. I have to train a couple of people who will be living this process for a month or so I have to get it right.

Thanks, Zach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Full disclosure: I work at Ektron)

Without being able to use eSync, your steps are on the right path, and you're really close. 
Only things that I see you missed were:

- root\uploadedimages
- root\uploadedfiles
- root\widgets (if any are custom)
- You mentioned assets, not sure if that includes root\privateassets as well

Things that are important:
Sitepath (in web.config) remains the same, eg:
www.mysite.com moved to something like sub.mysite.com or mysite.com/sub could potentially break any hard links within content or quicklinks/aliases depending how it's setup.. so just make sure the architecture remains as close as possible (folder structure on server being the same will also be safest, eg all sites get installed to .

Comment: Andrew, I was planning on keeping everything exactly the same (paths, site name in IIS, database name, db password, location of assetlibrary).  I was also planning on grabbing the entire website including the bin folder (with its 9 patches), workarea, uploadedfiles, etc. and overwriting the minsite.

Comment: Sounds good then, James (eGandalf) highlights a few good ideas in his post as well that works in conjunction with mine. Just thought of something else, if any changes are made in app_code you want to pull that across as well. (Not sure if any of your patches touch that)

Comment: Andrew is completely correct about the sitepath - it must stay the same. New/different subdomains are _usually_ ok. But as Andrew points out, can be problematic if you have anything hard-coded in your own code or within content (links, images).

It's best to assume that App_Code files are affected by SPs, but if you apply the same SPs to the destination server, it shouldn't matter. You'll of course want to copy over your own classes and any of Ektron's you've modified.

Answer (score 2):

The process you've outlined is more or less the same as that in the documentation, except you're setting up a min site first - which is how I usually do it, too. This should work fine. A couple of points to note:

- The version you are copying TO must be exactly the same as that you are copying FROM, including service packs.
- You should migrate changes to the .config files, especially web.config, by hand; do NOT overwrite the web.config of the new site with that of the old site.
- Make sure you update some Ektron-specific values, such as the WSPath.
- Apart from Assets, also copy PrivateAssets, UploadedFiles and UploadedImages.
- Try to not copy Ektron files that are included in the Min site from the old site to the new. It's best, and fastest, if you can only copy your own files or those you've modified.
- Once you've copied the site over, make sure to review it as thoroughly as possible to ensure that the copy was a success and that there are no errors resulting from the move.

It's generally best to only copy your own files from one site/server to the next. This is where Source Control (I use SVN) works out best. For example, if you put all your own code files, or those you've modified, into SVN (or similar) you could then set up a Min site on the destination server, backup and restore your DB, then "check out" or export your files from SVN into the root of the site, followed by updating the config files manually.

UPDATE: Full disclosure: I work at Ektron; Andrew's post reminded me to add that.

Comment: This process worries me as we have so many sites to move and manually pulling out our files from the base install would be too time consuming. I agree that it's the cleanest method but I know we can afford to be that granular.

Comment: You are **probably** ok in copying the whole site over. If you've not modified anything within, say, ~/workarea, I'd not copy it since the min site gives you everything you need. The one thing I would absolutely not copy directly over is the web.config. In that, at least, I think it would be worthwhile to be granular.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the site package utility, though I don't know the extent of what it includes and excludes.

From [my blog](http://ektroneering.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/deploying-ektron-site-via-packagesite.html)-

**Basic method-**

1. On your UAT server, run 
   `C:\Program Files\Ektron\CMS400v80\Utilities\PackageSite\PackageSite.exe` and
   follow the instructions

   - When asked to provide a folder to store the
     package, create a new, empty folder. The package is not zipped, its
     a collection of folders
   - The package contains 3 folders –
     assetlibrary, content, setup
2. Zip up your package and upload to your production server
3. Run the Ektron setup, but don’t setup a site. Just install the Ektron program files. Unzip the package into the `C:\Program Files\Ektron\CMS400v80\StarterSites`
4. Run site setup and
   you should be able to select your site from the starter site drop
   down.

**Some caveats-**

- The content folder included all the .svn Subversion folders and eSync certificates. So on the plus side it didn’t miss anything.
- Any thing you’ve added to web.config will be lost. Consider putting it into Application.config, or add it yourself.

Comment: We have used the site packager and it certainly gets everything, files, database, assets, etc.  However, for some reason it has an unknown size limitation where it begins losing files.  That makes me very nervous.